# How to take transpose of a big.matrix object?

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata, r-bigmemory

How to take transpose of a big.matrix object?

I have a 8000 x 8000 big.matrix object and I need to perform transpose and multiplication. How to do it?

`b <- as.big.matrix(basis)`

`bTransb <- t(b) %*% b`

This gives me the following error

`Error in t.default(b) : argument is not a matrix`

I have imported bigalgebra library. Still not working.

Comment: `library(bigpca)` seems to indicate that it contains `functions for transposing, using multicore 'apply' functionality, data importing and for compact display of big.matrix objects.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure with {bigmemory}, but you can do it with {bigstatsr} (disclaimer: I'm the author), which uses a similar format.

```
# Sample data
a <- matrix(0, 8000, 8000); a[] <- rnorm(length(a))
# devtools::install_github("privefl/bigstatsr")
library(bigstatsr)
b <- as_FBM(a)
class(b)
btrans <- big_crossprodSelf(b)
dim(btrans)
class(btrans)
# Verification
all.equal(btrans[], crossprod(b[]))
```

Comment: I am unable to install the devtools::install_github way. Is there any other way I can install it?

Comment: Why is that? You can clone the repo locally and build it yourself in RStudio with Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + B.

Comment: Blocked by IT sec, I think. It says `Installation failed: Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com` when I tried installing.

Comment: I used linear algebra techniques to mitigate the issue altogether. So, nope. Didn't install.

Comment: @xkcvk2511 Note that {bigstatsr} is now on CRAN too.

Comment: Awesome, I can give a try. @F. Privé